# reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping available: expected single matching bean but found 2: ,controllerEndpointHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

this is the error:

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
```

gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "io.mateo.cxf-codegen" version "1.0.1"
}

ext {
    jacksonXmlVersion = '2.13.3'
    resilience4jVersion = '1.7.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':domain-model')
    implementation project.ext.webflux
    implementation project.ext.mapstruct
    annotationProcessor project.ext.mapstructprocessor
    implementation("javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1")
    implementation('javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1')
    implementation("com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:2.0.1")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0")

    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.7.8')
    implementation ("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:${resilience4jVersion}")
    implementation ("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:${resilience4jVersion}")
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.8')

    implementation("com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:${jacksonXmlVersion}")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonXmlVersion}")
    cxfCodegen ("jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:2.3.3")
    cxfCodegen ("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5")
}
```

It is a project based on a hexagonal architecture, mainly oriented to webflux

The project is autoconfigured, how can I make it so that it only uses the actuator reactive beans?